# Duplicate key and table field in one-to-zero-or-one relation

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

For a metaphor here, a person can have zero or one car, and one car belongs only to one person.

I have a database that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a link from the person to its car, if existent, and from the car to its person. So my EntityTypeConfigurations are like so:

```
public class PersonConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblPerson");

        HasKey(s => s.Id)
            .Property(s => s.Id)
            .HasColumnName("idPerson");

        Property(s => s.Name)
            .HasColumnName("strName")
            .IsRequired();

        HasOptional(a => a.Car)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal();
    }
}

public class CarConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public CarConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblCar");

        HasKey(s => s.PersonId)
            .Property(s => s.PersonId)
            .HasColumnName("idPerson");

        Property(s => s.Model)
            .HasColumnName("strModel")
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(a => a.Person)
            .WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm getting wrong, but EF:

- Creates an additional `Person_Id` field in `tblCar`
- Creates two foreign keys in `tblCar`, one named `idPerson` and the other `Person_Id`

What am I forgetting or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `WithRequired` instead of `WithOptionalPrincipal`, and the relationship do not need to be configured in both sides.

```
public class PersonConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public TaskConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblPerson");

        HasKey(s => s.Id);

        Property(s => s.Id)
            .HasColumnName("idPerson");

        Property(s => s.Name)
            .HasColumnName("strName")
            .IsRequired();

        HasOptional(a => a.Car)
            .WithRequired(s => s.Person);
    }
}

public class CarConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public CarConfig()
    {
        ToTable("tblCar");

        HasKey(s => s.PersonId)
            .Property(s => s.PersonId)
            .HasColumnName("idPerson");

        Property(s => s.Model)
            .HasColumnName("strModel")
            .IsRequired();

        //not necessary
        //HasRequired(a => a.Person)
            //.WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I forgetting or doing wrong?

You are not configuring the `Person` - `Car` relationship correctly.

Let fix that. Note that you don't need to configure the relationship in both places.

Remove the following from the `Person` config:

```
   HasOptional(a => a.Car)
        .WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

and replace the following in the `Car` config:

```
   HasRequired(a => a.Person)
        .WithRequiredDependent();
```

with

```
   HasRequired(c => c.Person)
        .WithOptional(p => p.Car);
```